# python: submit variable to main program

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a program as below:

first,I plot a picture:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y,'ro')
ax.set_title('click on points')
plt.show()
```

then when I right-click the picture.It will zoom-in,and I'll pick one point on the zoom-in picture:

```
def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    if event.button==3:
        '''
        function zoom-in
        '''
        plt.show()
        onepoint = pylab.ginput(1)
return True
```

below is the command that can call "onclick" function

```
cid= fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

the qusetion is "how can I submit the variable "onepoint" which I got in "onclick"function to main program"

Comment: Why don't you just return it from the function?  If you need to still return True just do "return True, onepoint"

Comment: I can't.If I "return True, onepoint", variable "onepoint" always returns me "6",I don't know what's this mean but obviously it's not the right answer.

Comment: If it's giving you 6 then it is 6.  If onepoint shouldn't always be 6 then there is a bug that doesn't have anything to do with the return statement.

Comment: the question is: If I don't return onepoint,just "return True",then I use "cid= fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)" command call "onclick" function, when I type "cid",it still returns me "6",so I think maybe there are some special ways to call or return "click" functions just like this.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tacaswell/3144287 this may be of interest, it implements zooming with the scroll wheel.  You can probably adapt it by just changing the triggers

Comment: @ecline6 You can't just return it because this function gets called as a call-back and the return values don't get pushed back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global variable.  Declare the var outside the function:

```
onepoint = 0
```

And then tell your function that you will be using it like this:

```
def onclick(event):
    global onepoint

    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    if event.button==3:
        '''
        function zoom-in
        '''
        plt.show()
        onepoint = pylab.ginput(1)
    return True
```

Any changes that the function makes to the variable will affect it globally.